# How to clean all the identites from Sailpoint?

Tags: sailpoint

I want to clean all the identities and their accounts roles etc associated with identities.

Is there any way to bulk delete identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have shell access? 
You can use the iiq console for this:

```
bash /path/to/iiq/WEB-INF/bin/iiq console
> delete Identity *
```

This should get rid of all identities except for the ones which are tagged as protected. Also all additional data (links, assignedRoles, scorecards,..) will be deleted.